# Postgres: Problems using insert with select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_master (
  gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('wp_master_gid_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(80),
  ....
  type integer DEFAULT 4,
  CONSTRAINT p_key PRIMARY KEY (gid),
);
```

I want to insert data into the table from another table so I

```
insert into wp_master ( name, .... type) select "NAME", ...., 1 from ."Tiri2011";
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "p_key"
DETAIL:  Key (gid)=(2) already exists.
```

Why is postgres trying to put anything into the gid field when I have explicitly not included it in the list of columns?  I assumed that gid pick up its value from the sequence.

Russell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is trying to insert the next value of the `wp_master_gid_seq` sequence. Declaring an id column as `serial` (auto-increment) will create a sequence which has a stored value of the last inserted id which was auto-incremented. If at anytime you inserted a gid value manually, it bypassed the sequence and the autoincrement function may become broken, because the sequence value did not get updated accordingly.

The easiest way to fix it is to change the value of the sequence to the (max gid value of your table) + 1. Just execute this once and you should be ok

```
select setval('wp_master_gid_seq', coalesce((select max(id)+1 from wp_master), 1), false)
```

Comment: I thought I had done just that:
    
    CREATE SEQUENCE base.wp_master_gid_seq
      INCREMENT 1
      MINVALUE 1
      MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
      START 114
      CACHE 1;

Comment: I did try the setval as well but the problems still remains.

`select max(gid) from base.wp_master ;`

returns 113

Comment: I've figured it out.  The issue was that the sequence was in another schema so no matter what I did to the sequence in the same schema as the table it had no effect.  I've accepted Foibs' answer because although it did not actually answer the question it did give me vital information that I used to solve it.